# sed: keep last chunk of each word containing chunk pattern

Tags: shell, sed

Willing to keep only last chunk of words containing a dot (still keeping words not containing pattern):

sed seems to only match last word:

```
$ echo "Here this.is.a.start is a very.nice.String  that.is.the.end yes " | sed 's/.*[ ]\([^ ]*\.\)\([^ ]*\)[ ].*/\2/g'
end

$ echo "Here this.is.a.start is a very.nice.String  that.is.the.end yes " | sed 's/.*[ ]\([^ ]*\.\)\([^ ]*\)[ ].*/\1/g'
that.is.the.
```

how should I do to get this result ? :

```
echo "Here this.is.a.start is a very.nice.String  that.is.the.end yes " | sed s\\\g
Here start is a String  end yes
```

Comment: Can you please add a bit more clarity on requirements and more examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
sed -E 's/([^ .]+\.)+([^ .]+)/\2/g'
sed -E 's/([^[:space:].]+\.)+([^[:space:].]+)/\2/g'
```

The `[:space:]` will account for any whitespace, not just a space char.

See an [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/LQtBPL):

```sh
echo "     * {@link my.tailor.is.rich but( ther.is.a.hole.in.my.pants )}. " | \
 sed -E 's/([^ .]+\.)+([^ .]+)/\2/g'
# => "     * {@link rich but( pants )}. "
```

**Details**

- `([^ .]+\.)+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `[^ .]+` - any one or more chars other than a space and a dot
  - `\.` - a dot
- `([^ .]+)` - Group 2: any one or more chars other than a space and a dot.

Comment: Have been generous in giving one point because: `echo "     * {@link my.tailor.is.rich but( ther.is.a.hole.in.my.pants )}. " | sed 's/\([^ .]*\.\)\{1,\}\([^ .]*\)/\2/g'`    miss the end of the string: * {@link rich but( pants

Answer (score 2):

With \w for a word:

```
echo "Here this.is.a.start is a very.nice.String  that.is.the.end yes " |
 sed -E 's/\w*\.//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Only match that what you want to replace. The `.*[ ]` matches *everything* - what for. You just want to replace `something.dot.something`- match as small as possible.

```
echo "Here this.is.a.start is a very.nice.String  that.is.the.end yes " |
 sed 's/\(^\| \)[^ ]*\.\([^ ]\)/\1\2/g'
```

- `\(^\| \)` match beginning of the line or a space and remember it in `\1`
- `[^ ]*\.` - match any text up followed by a dot
- `\([^ ]\)` - match any text and remember in `\2`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew answer is good also, KamilCuk one came first .. Thank you both

Comment: No worries - but please pick a random one and accept it, so the question is closed and appears so on our forum.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ s="Here this.is.a.start is a very.nice.String  that.is.the.end yes "

$ # if you know the characters that make up the words
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/[a-z.]*\.//ig'
Here start is a String  end yes 

$ # a field based approach
$ echo "$s" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/.*\./, "", $i)} 1'
Here start is a String end yes
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/([^. ]+\.)+//g' file
```

Delete globally groups of one or more non-period/spaces followed by a period.